# error: not a statement, How do I fix this?

Tags: java, if-statement, error-handling

```
        System.out.Println("Do you want to continue ?");
            if 
                (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    LinkedTeams.createList();       
                }

            else 
                (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
```

The error happens on the Else part of the statement below, Im now wondering what i did wrong because I'm unable to see any mistakes with semi colons or the regular trouble

```
{
                        MainMenu.MENU();
                    }       
            }while()    

        }

                public static void printList()
                            {

                                currentNode=headNode;

                                while (currentNode!=null)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(currentNode.pokemonName);
                            Im unable to differentiate the difference between the two 

            System.out.println(currentNode.pokemonType);

                                        currentNode=currentNode.next;
                Just unable to find enough information                  }   
                            }






}
```

Comment: you need to know the basis of a language before start coding with it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.Println("Do you want to continue ?");
            if 
                (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    LinkedTeams.createList();       
                }

            else if 
                (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
```

else does not take statement because it is already a reached part. Adding an "if" should solve.

Answer (score 1):

You meant `else if` and not just `else`: [if-then and if-then-else statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).